# What are some Qualitative test/s that you can use for benzophenone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, separation-techniques

I have determined one of my unknowns to be benzophenone and in a lab setting (but that isn't possible because of COVID-19) I would conducted the 2,4 DNP test which should yield a positive result. However, I am a bit stuck on other tests that would make it very definitive that a ketone is present.

I know if I use the following test, I would get the following results:

1. The Tollen's test- it would be negative because an aldehyde isn't present
2. The iodoform test- would be negative because the ketone on benzophenone would be negative
3. The Chromic Acid test- would be negative because Aldehydes are oxidized by chromic acid, ketones are not.

But are there any other tests that can be used?

I have seen the previous post on this question dated back to 4 years ago and it didn't really help.

Comment: It would give negative Schiff's test, Benedict and Fehling's test.

Comment: Take an mp of sublimed material (benzophenone, mp 48.5oC). Reduce with NaBH4 to benzhydrol (mp. 69oC).  Dissolve unknown in anhydrous THF under nitrogen. Add sodium. Blue sodium benzophenone ketyl forms.

Comment: Not really, I had seen that post.